# XML RSS feed using PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm using the following code to piece together a series of variables declared further back in the script to form the link portion of a RSS XML feed. I need to insert a ampersand between the variables to complete the URL properly.  I've tried using & and also just & put it ends up with an error:

`error on line 7 at column 194: Entity Ref: expecting ';'`

Can somebody please show me so I can see what I am doing wrong?

```
echo '<link>' . $url . 'ampersand_goes_here' . $mlcall. '' . $title . '</link>';
```

Comment: `what am I doing wrong?` You're not using something like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to generate your XML for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enclosing the string within the link tag with the htmlspecialchars() function.

```
echo '<link>' . htmlspecialchars($url . 'ampersand_goes_here' . $mlcall. '' . $title) . '</link>';
```

Comment: can you show me the proper syntax within the example provided please?

Comment: Well you might as well replace 'ampersand_goes_here' by & then. :) This call will indeed transform it into the html entity `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<link>$url&amp;$mlcall$title</link>";
```

or (better yet)

```
echo '<link>' . htmlentities($url&$mlcall$title) . '</link>';
```